# Make Variable available outside of function

Tags: bash, function, shell, variables

I had some help previously on generating some Variables from a file which has worked a treat.

The problem I have now is that this procedure is held as a function and the declare is within that function.

Is there a way to use the variable declared outside of the function? I just get a blank row returned

```
getVARS () {

while IFS== read -r name value; do
    if [[ $name == \#* ]] || [[ $name == \-\-* ]]; then
      echo $name" ignored"
    else
      declare -x "$name=$value"
    fi
done < /home/admin/file.dat

unset IFS

}
```

The function above is held in a separate script and called in this way...

```
. /home/admin/functions

getVARS
echo "$VarA"
```

Comment: You may try declaring those variable outside the function. That way, they will be within the scope of the function which will be able to assign values, which in turn will be visible once the function completes.

Comment: You can save/restore variables from/to file, or use named pipes. You can pipe the output of the function to other commands. You can also return a value, if you only require a single value.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I do need all the variables which are read from the file, but I would ideally like to keep them as a function for neatness. I suppose I could strip the function part of it and just include it in my script as and when needed.

Comment: Have you tried `export $name=$value`?

Comment: @alnet thank you, that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is using **declare**

In man of declare you can read:

> When used in a function, declare makes each name local, as with the
>   local command.

So if you want to use outside of your function you can use:

```
eval $name=$value
```

or

```
export $name=$value
```

Comment: Thank you, both these options work. Can I ask the benefit of using eval or export? or is there no difference?

Comment: Don't use `eval`. As an example, if `name=foo` and `value='3;echo hi'`, the value of `name is not `3;echo hi`; it's `3`, and then `echo hi` is executed.

Comment: @RichardC if you use export all child process will see the declared var

Answer (score 1):

Starting in `bash` 4.2, you can add the `-g` option to `declare` to make the variable global instead of local

```
getVARS () {

  while IFS== read -r name value; do
    if [[ $name == \#* ]] || [[ $name == \-\-* ]]; then
      echo $name" ignored"
    else
      declare -gx "$name=$value"
    fi
  done < /home/admin/file.dat
}
```

Note that you don't need to unset `IFS`; the purpose of putting the assignment just prior to `read` is to localize the change to that command.